# An easy vegan meal plan that covers all dietary needs

Tags: veganism, diet, nutrition, cooking

If you want to get enough of a particular nutrient X, there are always plenty of resources showing how to do so. For example, here are articles showing how to get enough [protein](http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/protein.php), [calcium](http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/calcium.php), and [iron](http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/iron.php). They include meal plans for the whole day and break down the numbers to prove that there's enough of the given nutrient. However you can't follow all the meal plans at once, so it's not clear how to get enough of ALL nutrients every day.

Moreover, it's hard to find meal plans and recipes that are easy, quick, and affordable. Recipes tend to be written by people who love cooking and want their food to taste amazing. In my experience recipes that claim to be quick and easy are usually not, at least not to me.

Can I get meal plans that are vegan, meet all (or almost all - it doesn't have to be perfect) nutritional requirements, and don't require a lot of time, money, effort, or skill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.vrg.org/journal/vj2003issue1/2003_issue1_quick.php) has meal plans for several days with an emphasis on being quick and low-cost. I haven't tried following it myself, but it does indeed look easy enough to follow. It says "The menus were planned to meet the average person's needs for most nutrients over a week-long period." It doesn't actually show nutrient values in the article, but I entered the foods for [day 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ygmD.png) and [day 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32tdm.png) into [cronometer](https://cronometer.com/) and the results were promising. They fall just a little short on omega-3 and only have about half the required vitamin D (which can be improved with sunlight).

The website also has several other articles on meal plans [here](http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/#nutrition-meal-plans).